# Java Threads vs Pthreads

Tags: java, multithreading, posix

I was asked this question in an interview today.

"When we create a thread with `pthread_create()` (POSIX Threads), the thread starts on its own. Why do we need to explicitly call `start()` in Java. What is the reason that Java doesnt start the thread when we create an instance of it."

I was blank and interviewer was short of time and eventually he couldn't explain the reason to me.

Comment: So your interviewer couldn't explain the answer either? :) hehe

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In Java not starting the thread right away leads to a better API.  You can set properties on the thread (daemon, priority) without having to set all the properties in the constructor.

If the thread started right away, it would need a constructor,

```
public Thread(Runnable target, String name, ThreadGroup threadGroup, int priority, boolean daemon, ContextClassLoader contextClassLoader, long stackSize)
```

To allow setting all these parameters before the thread started.  The daemon property can't be set after the thread has started.

I'm guessing that the POSIX API takes a struct with all the thread properties in the call to `pthread_create()`, so it makes sense to start the thread right away.

Comment: The posix API does indeed take a struct containing all the thread properties. The struct in question is a pthread_attr_t. As to which approach is better, I can't take a side. It's highly dependent on what you're comfortable with. Neither has any real technical benefits over another, it's just how the API is exposed.

Comment: *Since none of these parameters can be changed once the thread has started.* `Name` sure can at any time. it's kept in the java heap and has no representation in the native OS part. The classloader  (ccl), however, is Changed A LOT during execution and changing is its prime goal. Priority can be altered as well. Daemon can be changed at any time as well.

Comment: @bestsss: [`setDaemon()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon(boolean)) "must be called before the thread is started.".

Comment: @Varun: in that case creating the `struct` is in fact the same as creating the `Thread` object. Populating its fields is done in a similar way in Java (using setters instead of direct field access) and calling `pthread_create` is equivalent to calling `start()` then. The two APIs are more similar than they seem at first glance, then.

Comment: @Joachim, this is true, daemon can be changed only before start, and after death

Comment: @bestsss: why after death? Nothing in the doc suggests this is possible and it would have no effect anyway.

Comment: @Joachim, about no effect after death - of course, actually at 1st I was thinking that daemon is inherited by the currentThread and then got mixed up, that the currentThread cannot  have it changed any more; `IllegalThreadStateException  if this thread is active.` . *Active*, after it's dead, it's not active any more.

Comment: Thread.setContextClassLoader(...) can be any number of times (even while thread is running);

Answer (score 5):

The reasons are a lot. But I'll give you a few:

- The thread, itself, might start executing before returning the instance.
- The context classloader MUST be set properly before running the thread (look at the previous point)
- Extra configuration like priority should be set before starting the thread
- pthreads uses a pointer to the initialized structure(s), since the java.lang.Thread cannot be properly initialized in the end of the c-tor, see points above; straight call to the native `pthread_create` to actually execute the code makes no sense

I hope you get the idea.